# How is the quadrantal rule applied to VFR flights in Hungary?

Tags: navigation, easa-regulations, visual-flight-rules, ppl, flight-level

I'm looking for a clear explanation for this quadrantal rule question (it applies to Hungary):

> A VFR pilot is cruising, en-route in level flight, above the transition level of FL035. His magnetic heading is 355°, and he sees that by having allowed for 8° of starboard drift he is exactly on track. What would be an appropriate Flight Level for the pilot to choose in accordance with the Quadrantal Rule?

Comment: What country does this apply to?

Comment: Hungary. This question is from a PPL theory questions book.

Comment: I've added that information to your question - in the future if an answer to your question will apply to a particular nation's regulations, it's good to request it up front. Otherwise you'll get lots of answers that don't help you.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! I made a few small changes to your question, if I got something wrong then feel free to edit again yourself. I assumed that "FL35" means "FL035" and not "FL350" in this case (because you said it was the transition level).

Comment: @pondlife. I’m being obtuse here, but personal pet-peeve: Heading is 035, FL is only 35

Comment: @Radu094 No problem :-) But maybe it's a regional thing? In the US, flight levels always have three digits. And in South Africa, come to think of it.

Comment: Oh, could be a regional....can’t find anything official about it ... maybe an ATC guy can help enlighten us

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is about Hungary, the answer will be in [Hungary's AIP](https://ais-en.hungarocontrol.hu/aip/2015-11-12-final/).

[ENR 1.2](https://ais-en.hungarocontrol.hu/aip/2015-11-12-final/2015-11-12-AIRAC/html/eAIP/LH-ENR-1.2-en-HU.html#ENR-1.2) says:

> 2.6. VFR flights in level cruising flight, when operated above 3 500 FT (1 050 M) MSL, **shall** be conducted at a level appropriate to the **track** specified in the table of cruising levels (ENR 1.7 para 3.).

(Emphasis mine.)

And by referencing that table ([PDF](https://ais-en.hungarocontrol.hu/aip/2015-11-12-final/2015-11-12-AIRAC/graphics/eAIP/ENR%201_7%20Table.pdf)) in ENR 1.7, it becomes clear Hungary uses a semicircular/hemispheric, and not a quadrantal rule.

The pilot's starboard drift will make their actual track 355 + 8 = 003°. VFR flights use the IFR rule + 500 *(see below),* so for this "eastbound" flight the pilot should fly odd + 500, an example would be FL 55.

[image]
(Hungarian eAIP)

Answer (score 1):

The direction of the ground track is what matters, not the actual aircraft heading.

Answer (score 0):

The Quadrantal Rule is not binding on aircraft flying VFR, but if the pilot still wants to stick to the rule, he/she should climb to FL045. The rule was "Even plus 500 on magnetic tracks from 270 degrees up to and including 359 degrees." and does not apply at all below FL 030.